# How do I generate mipmap .png and model .obj files for LibGDX?

Tags: textures, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm playing a bit with LibGDX (OpenGL ES 2.0 wrapper for Android).

I found some sample code which used prepared files to load models and mipmap textures for them, e.g., at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/invaders/gdx-invaders/src/com/badlogic/gdxinvaders/RendererGL20.java it reads .obj file for the model and RGB565 format .png file to apply a mipmapped texture to it.

What is the best / easiest way for me to create these files?

I understand .obj files are generated by a bunch of tools (I installed Blender, Wings3D and Kerkythea so far), but which ones will be the most user friendly for someone unfamiliar with 3D modelling?

But more importantly, how do I produce a .png file with the mipmapped texture? The .png I looked at ( https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/invaders/gdx-invaders/data/ship.png ) seems to include different textures for each of the faces, probably created with some tool. I browsed through the menus for the 3 tools I have installed but didn't find an option to export such a .png file. What am I missing?

Comment: libGDX will do the mipmap automatic for you. It will use your texture as the main one, and generate/use the optimized ones. I think what you want is a [TexturePacker](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/).

Comment: Yes, I know it can do multiple resized textures in one mipmap. 

But I think here something else has been done - the textures for all planes for a particular mesh have been stored in one .png.

Are you sure TexturePacker tool does that?

Comment: that is exactly what is does. This tool packs many smalls ".png" into a single file. You can load each small piece as a `sprite` in libGDX. If you want to use the result texture in a 3D model, you will have to manually do the `UV-Mapping` with your favorite 3D modeler tool...

Comment: Ah, the UV-Mapping keyword is helpful. I somehow had missed it before. 

I will read some UV-Mapping tutorials for the tools I have installed, I think that is the method I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) + [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) for creating textures. After making the final model, select it, jump into edit mode, then press <kbd>u</kbd> (or *Mesh-> UV Unwrap*, on the lower menu bar) and select *Smart UV Project* and click *OK*. Then change the editor type to *UV/Image editor* (Blue arrow).

**If nothing is displayed, make sure all faces are selected.**

Now on the lower bar click *UVs -> Export UV Layout*. [GIMP magic happens there].
When you want to test testures, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> refreshes, go back to 3D view and select *textured display mode* (red arrow).

I've read that the `obj` format isn't the best one for libgdx and that `g3db` is better.
To obtain such a file, first download [fbx-conv](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv).
In Blender click *File -> Export -> Autodesk FBX*, and save it in the folder with fbx-conv.
then open command line\terminal and run:

```
fbx-conv.exe -f "filename.fbx"
```

**Note that you must add to assets both the .png and .g3db**
I used AssetManager to load the model.

[image: Where to click]